# How to find a value stored in a memory address on a machine that employs big-endian byte ordering

Tags: binary, endianness

So I am asked this question in class.

If I am given the instruction MOVE.L #$12345678,$8000 and this is executed on a machine that employs big-endian byte ordering, how would I find the value that is stored in the memory address at $8002? This is used on a Motorola 68K. I am very stuck with this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what big endian and little endian mean? See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With big-endian the most-significant byte of a word is stored at a particular memory address and the subsequent bytes are stored in the following higher memory addresses, the least significant byte thus being stored at the highest memory address.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

In your case, that means as you start writing data to memory address $8000, the most significant byte will be written to $8000, followed in order by successively less significant bytes

```
$8000: 12
$8001: 34
$8002: 56
$8003: 78
```